# How to install a Library for C++ like Eigen and sharkML at vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linear-algebra, eigen, shark

I am trying to install libraries like eigen, sharkMl, xtensor, and others in VSCode for C++.
Please if anyone can help me to know the right way to do that.

Comment: Eigen can be installed [from MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), along with an up-to-date GCC and a good build environment. The other two you'll probably have to build from source, they should include build instructions.

Answer (score 2):

All of these libraries use CMake for their build system so what I do is use CMake as my build system. My favorite way to do this is to use the libraries build systems to install them and then inlcude them with cmakes `find_package` function. This you can do by cloning the git repository for the library then build it and install it with cmake. On linux you do this by:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
cd eigen
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

VSCode has good integration for cmake so if you have the **C/C++ Extension pack** you will be able to build with cmake. In your project folder make a CMakeLists.txt file and add the packages you want:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)    
find_package(Eigen3 3.4 NO_MODULE)
target_link_libraries(main Eigen3::Eigen)
```

(This example assumes the main cpp file is main.cpp and creates an executable called main) Then when you press ctr+shift+p and perform CMake: Configure you can select your compiler and build the executable.